# Unable to start tomcat server in netbeans and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging, netbeans

I am trying to run Tomcat 6.0.18 from Netbeans 6.7 but getting the following output
on the server console.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

I have tried reinstalling , tried different versions of tomcat viz. 6.0.24 , 7.0.16 , 5.5 etc  , shifted from eclipse to netbeans to but don't why it is coming. In one of the replies for the same it was suggested to add $CATALINA_HOME\bin\tomcat-juli.jar to the launch configuraton in case of eclipse but in netbeans this library along with the others in **lib** folder have already been added. still the situation is same :(

Comment: Have you ever tried starting Tomcat from the commandline itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this , it has solved the problem

it seems that the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file in the `bootstrap.jar` contains a no reference for

`tomcat-juli.jar`

just add/update this entry in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file in the `bootstrap.jar`

```
Class-Path: commons-daemon.jar tomcat-juli.jar
```

and then try to run the tomcat sever

Comment: After changing the MANIFEST.MF file, do we have to create a jar again.

Answer (score 1):

Hi，I have just begun to learn, also encountered the same problem, and finally I get through the following steps:

1. Tomcat v7.0 Apache Open,
2. Information Overview in General launch
3. Open configuration >Edit >Configuration, >Classpath, >Entries,
4. External    TOMCAT_HOME/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
5. restart your lomboz

For more information,you can view this picture,hope this will fix your problems.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the `tomcat-juli.jar` (or whichever JAR contains `org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory`) isn't added to the classpath.

You don't say how you start tomcat (Eclipse Tomcat plugin, Web Tools, ANT script, ...) so it's hard to say why it's not there. If you can, add a breakpoint in `URLClassLoader.java:202` and examine the result of calling `getURLs()` (see point #5 in [5 Tips for Debugging Java Code in Eclipse](http://www.cavdar.net/2008/09/13/5-tips-for-debugging-java-code-in-eclipse/)).

Comment: Hi Aaron ,
I am using netbeans 6.7 for the same. At the last line of logs that are produced , it is saying "Could not find main class".

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
      
.
.
.
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 1 more
Could not find the main class: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main".

Comment: I am working in windows , from there I tried _startup.bat_  but the result is same.

Comment: Excellent. That means you Tomcat installation is incomplete. Download and install it again.

Comment: I have done it many times and again repeated i , same issue coming again and again on all installations.

Comment: Follow my advice to get the classpath. My guess is that tomcat-juli.jar isn't added to the classpath; the startup.bat script should do that. Does tomcat start if you don't change anything after installing it? Did you try it on a different computer?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap.jar is missing that is why this Exception is coming